# How to extract and print the correct value while decoding the protobuf in Python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

```
(Pdb) p mac
'\xd0\xbf\x9c\xd8\xf0\x00'
p type(mac)
<type 'str'>
```

Using Python2.7, how can I extract and print the exact MAC-address?
In .proto message, mac_address is defined as 
"optional bytes mac".

Comment: Isn't there a way to decode it and see the contents. Why people are going into string formatting.which is not what I am looking for..

Comment: Maybe you could show what your desired result would look like for your given example string, since 'decode' could mean many different things.

Answer (score 0):

```
import struct
a='\xd0\xbf\x9c\xd8\xf0\x00'
for i in range(6):
  print hex(struct.unpack("B", a[i])[0])[2:], ":",
```

prints

```
d0 : bf : 9c : d8 : f0 : 0 :
```

Comment: Not like this. I mean the protobuf that I received as some variables as strings and some mac.. When I print it, all variables which are defined in .proto as ints, strings are coming just fine, except for the one whose type is bytes. Isn't there a more generic way to display.

Answer (score 0):

This perhaps?

```
>>> mac_str = ':'.join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in mac)
>>> print(mac_str)
d0:bf:9c:d8:f0:00
```

If you just want the list of ints do:

```
mac_decoded = [ord(c) for c in mac]
```

Not sure what else you mean by 'decoded'...

Answer (score 0):

```
':'.join([hex(c)[2:] for c in map(ord,'\xd0\xbf\x9c\xd8\xf0\x00')])
```

Prints:

```
'd0:bf:9c:d8:f0:0'
```

Basically, this line converts the hex string into a list of 0-to-255 range ints and then convert each element c back into a hex string without the '\x' characters and then join the list elements as a string with a ':' in-between.

Comment: You can also do `r'\xd0\xbf\x9c\xd8\xf0\x00'.replace(r'\x','',1).replace(r'\x',':')` Which is much more cleaner

Comment: I don't think there is a direct type-casting approach to this. Maybe you could achieve prettier results with regex.